# Sending a response after app starting from a intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to implement the PICK and SET_WALLPAPER intent-filter, and so far I've got them in the context menu, but how do I respond back to whoever started the app that way? Lets say I have the activity:

```
<activity
    android:name="ListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When this activity is successfully running, and I know what image (I know it's location on external storage, and could have a Bitmap of it), how do I send this response back so that the app that started my app can use the response? I'm thinking finish(), but what extras do I then add? Does this come down to the specific app that started my app? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/645387) for an example of returning from an intent called with startActivityForResult(). I'm assuming that's how it is called from the system. However, I don't know what sort of result you need respond with.

[edit] Actually I don't think you have to return anything. Just set your wallpaper with the WallpaperManager or whatever and finish() your activity.

Comment: The link has been expired. please can you provide useful link.

Comment: Updated the link to link to point to a pretty good SO answer for startActivityForResult.